# Can I create a matrix of buttons in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have to program a minesweeper game in c++, I was thinking in use the visual c++ to create the board and use a matrix of buttons so that I can just reference them  like button[1][2] or something like that but I'm really new to visual c++ and I have no idea how to do this or even if it's possible. Can you tell me if it's possible or not and, if is, show me how or point me to a tutorial or example that help me do such thing?

I'm using visual c++ express

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which UI library are you using?

Comment: Up to now all I used to the graphic part I did was the visual c++ components, do I need to use a UI library to do this type of things?

Comment: No, that is not what I was asking. You are already using a library.  What is the project type?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. It wa a windows form application

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you don't need to. In fact, I would strongly advise to NOT create individual buttons for every field in the Minesweeper's grid. What benefit would you get from those buttons? A click event? Then you would have to translate that button's ID into its X,Y position, do some processing in your matrix, set text or an image to that button.

This all can be achieved by drawing the grid yourself, handling mouse clicks and converting the coordinates into indexes in your matrix.

Two more unsolicited suggestions:

1. Window Forms are overrated. Is there a reason you chose that
   framework for your project?
2. Express editions of Visual Studio make no sense since introduction of modern Community Editions.